# Best wireless mouse/keyboard for conference room computer?

Tags: wireless-keyboard, wireless-mouse

What would be the best wireless mouse and keyboard for a conference room computer that is used by multiple employees throughout the day?  We have one in there right now that is really cheap that doesn't work half the time.  This is due to the fact that the batteries run down when left on... and it seems to have problems losing its pairing with the computer dongle.

Any ideas on something that won't have battery problems, is very reliable and somewhat tough?  Price isn't too much of an issue, but I'd still prefer to get something for less than $100 just in case someone walks away with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the Gyration Intelligent AirMouse Featuring Motionsense with a Gyration Go Pro.  It lets you use the Mouse in the air as well as on a desk.  The keyboard is nice and compact and both the mouse and keyboard have great range.

Found via a cross-post at serverfault.. https://serverfault.com/questions/165385/conference-room-input-devices/165464#165464

Answer (score 0):

The Magic Mouse from Apple and the Apple Wireless Keyboard if you have a Mac. Both hardware are light, uses Bluetooth and do not have wires that you need to connect to your computer, and last really long on the batteries.

Answer (score 0):

I use this for my HTPC, and have recommended it to several others who are quite satisfied with it. It takes AA batteries, and they last quite a long time.  When not in use, the keyboard and mouse enter a power save mode--there's no on/off switch like with other wireless devices, as you mention as being a problem.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16823201035